# Login Form header() shows blank page

Tags: php, mysqli, xampp

I created a login form that should direct the user to the page after sending the form but it just shows me a blank page

with a link of **http://localhost/Cisu/AccHolder/holderlogin.php

**Login Form**

```
<?php 
session_start();
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html >
    <head>
            <title>Login</title>
            <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="css/login.css">
            </head>
            <body>
                <form method="" action="holderlogin.php">
                    <div class="container">
                        <div class="profile">
                            <button class="profile__avatar" id="toggleProfile">
                                <img src="images/sbma.png" alt="Avatar" />
                            </button>
                            <div class="profile__form">
                                <div class="profile__fields">
                                    <div class="field">
                                        <input type="text" id="user" name="user" class="input" required pattern=.*\S.* />
                                        <label for="username" class="label">Username</label>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="field">
                                        <input type="password" id="pass" name="pass" class="input" required pattern=.*\S.* />
                                        <label for="password" class="label">Password</label>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="profile__footer">
                                        <input id="Submit" name="Submit "type = "Submit" class="btn"/>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <script src="javascript/login.js"></script>
                </form>
            </body>
        </html>
```

**holderlogin.php**

```
<?php
ob_start();
session_start();

include('dbconn.php');// Database connection and settings

// checking the user

if(isset($_POST['Submit'])){

$user = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_POST['user']);

$pass = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_POST['pass']);

$sel_user = "select * from tbl_accholder where accholder_Username='$user' AND accholder_Password='$pass'";

$run_user = mysqli_query($con, $sel_user);

$check_user = mysqli_num_rows($run_user);

if($check_user==1){
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($run_user)) {
    $run_ID = $row['accholder_ID'];
    $run_user = $row['accholder_Username'];
}

$_SESSION['accholder_Username']= $user;
$_SESSION['accholder_ID']= $run_ID;

header( 'Location: MainMenu.php'); 

} else
                                echo "please wait while redirecting...";
                                echo "<script> alert('Log-In Failed!'); </script>";
                                echo "<script> document.location.href = 'Login.php' </script>";
ob_end_flush();
}


?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are checking whether `$_POST['Submit']` is set.

However, in your form, the `name` attribute is `Submit` with an extra space:

```
<input id="Submit" name="Submit "type = "Submit" class="btn"/>
```

This might be the cause of the problem, since you said it *shows me a blank page*.

Comment: it did not work 

i replace the header with just 

echo ''Correct'; 

to check if it is the header 
it shows blank so it must be my query

Comment: @JK.Constantine You have a space in your `name`, try removing the space, refer to my answer, thanks!

Comment: no just a blank page 

i checked my query, the column name of the table and the <input name=""> 
They are correct but what else could i checked ?

Comment: @JK.Constantine You have a space in your name attribute --> `name="Submit "`. Also, you might have duplicate rows in your DB, try `if($check_user>=1){` instead.

Comment: Thank you it fixed it seems thats the only mistake. I should have notice that, this is really embarrassing

Answer (score 0):

Don't know if its causing your problem, but you have a leading space before the php declaration - this can be cause problems to the php rendering if you are setting header requests later in the code - there can be no characters rendered before the header request.

```
<?php
```

also you list the action of the form as "holderlogin.php"

but list the name of the file as "Holderlogin.php" - this might just be a typo when entering the code here but worth checking.

Comment: oh sorry its just did that when i indent the code and 
the Holder login part just auto capitalized 
i will edit it

Answer (score 0):

also - you have no method listed for your form, but are checking the $_POST array to check for "Submit". It should be:

```
<form method="POST" action="holderlogin.php">
```

Comment: oh sorry i forgot that
i added that but it just shows a blank page after sending the form

Comment: the do you have a MainMenu.php in your file directory?

Comment: yes its in the same place as the holderlogin.php and Login Form